# Very slow query with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum, corrupt-data

```
I have a very serious problem with PostgreSQL 14. In practice, every 5 days or so my tables, or rather some, are corrupted. When I launch a simple query, it does not execute and it remains stuck.`enter code here`
```

This DB receives many write-to's in a day.
I think the table is corrupted. I would like to know why this happens if anyone has any ideas. Thank you all in advance.
I paste here an analyze that I did where I try to get the sum of some quantities in a month,

"QUERY PLAN"
"Aggregate  (cost=109583.25..109583.26 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=138615.457..138628.145 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=69650.26..109583.25 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=138569.160..138626.750 rows=17950 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=68650.26..108583.05 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=138556.409..138599.546 rows=5983 loops=3)"
"              Join Filter: (m.causale_id = caus.id)"
"              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 154159"
"              ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=68650.26..108581.15 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=138556.373..138560.611 rows=5983 loops=3)"
"                    Hash Cond: (rmdt.rigamovimentodettaglio_id = rmd.id)"
"                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on rigamovimentodettagliotaglia rmdt  (cost=0.00..36254.00 rows=980500 width=8) (actual time=0.006..73.938 rows=784833 loops=3)"
"                    ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=68650.24..68650.24 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=138344.297..138344.300 rows=3414 loops=3)"
"                          Buckets: 16384 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 760kB"
"                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=35906.91..68650.24 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=137726.906..137728.106 rows=3414 loops=3)"
"                                Hash Cond: (rmd.rigamovimento_id = r.id)"
"                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on rigamovimentodettaglio rmd  (cost=0.00..29574.42 rows=845042 width=16) (actual time=0.008..42.578 rows=676262 loops=3)"
"                                ->  Hash  (cost=35906.88..35906.88 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=137605.446..137605.448 rows=9221 loops=3)"
"                                      Buckets: 16384 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 561kB"
"                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..35906.88 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=39.893..137593.589 rows=9221 loops=3)"
"                                            ->  Index Scan using ukm9njdtmreayrcdjfln8chor0r on movimento m  (cost=0.42..12620.62 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.085..32.738 rows=3290 loops=3)"
"                                                  Index Cond: ((datamovimento >= '2023-01-01'::date) AND (datamovimento <= '2023-02-01'::date))"
"                                            ->  Index Scan using uk_6iar6gjj0t1e0tq5g60a93wou on rigamovimento r  (cost=0.43..23286.12 rows=15 width=16) (actual time=18.317..41.798 rows=3 loops=9870)"
"                                                  Index Cond: (movimento_id = m.id)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on causale caus  (cost=0.00..1.40 rows=40 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.003 rows=27 loops=17950)"
"Planning Time: 0.531 ms"
"JIT:"
"  Functions: 86"
"  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 7.836 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 3.694 ms, Emission 54.204 ms, Total 65.733 ms"
"Execution Time: 138630.701 ms"

```
this is my configuration in db:
"allow_in_place_tablespaces"    "off"
"allow_system_table_mods"   "off"
"application_name"  "pgAdmin 4 - CONN:8842897"
"archive_cleanup_command"   
"archive_command"   "(disabled)"
"archive_mode"  "off"
"archive_timeout"   "0"
"array_nulls"   "on"
"authentication_timeout"    "1min"
"autovacuum"    "on"
"autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor"   "0.1"
"autovacuum_analyze_threshold"  "50"
"autovacuum_freeze_max_age" "200000000"
"autovacuum_max_workers"    "3"
"autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age"   "400000000"
"autovacuum_naptime"    "1min"
"autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay"  "2ms"
"autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit"  "-1"
"autovacuum_vacuum_insert_scale_factor" "0.2"
"autovacuum_vacuum_insert_threshold"    "1000"
"autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor"    "0.2"
"autovacuum_vacuum_threshold"   "50"
"autovacuum_work_mem"   "-1"
"backend_flush_after"   "0"
"backslash_quote"   "safe_encoding"
"backtrace_functions"   
"bgwriter_delay"    "200ms"
"bgwriter_flush_after"  "512kB"
"bgwriter_lru_maxpages" "100"
"bgwriter_lru_multiplier"   "2"
"block_size"    "8192"
"bonjour"   "off"
"bonjour_name"  
"bytea_output"  "hex"
"check_function_bodies" "on"
"checkpoint_completion_target"  "0.9"
"checkpoint_flush_after"    "256kB"
"checkpoint_timeout"    "5min"
"checkpoint_warning"    "30s"
"client_connection_check_interval"  "0"
"client_encoding"   "UNICODE"
"client_min_messages"   "notice"
"cluster_name"  "14/main"
"commit_delay"  "0"
"commit_siblings"   "5"
"compute_query_id"  "auto"
"config_file"   "/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf"
"constraint_exclusion"  "partition"
"cpu_index_tuple_cost"  "0.005"
"cpu_operator_cost" "0.0025"
"cpu_tuple_cost"    "0.01"
"cursor_tuple_fraction" "0.1"
"data_checksums"    "off"
"data_directory"    "/var/lib/postgresql/14/main"
"data_directory_mode"   "0700"
"data_sync_retry"   "off"
"DateStyle" "ISO, MDY"
"db_user_namespace" "off"
"deadlock_timeout"  "1s"
"debug_assertions"  "off"
"debug_discard_caches"  "0"
"debug_pretty_print"    "on"
"debug_print_parse" "off"
"debug_print_plan"  "off"
"debug_print_rewritten" "off"
"default_statistics_target" "100"
"default_table_access_method"   "heap"
"default_tablespace"    
"default_text_search_config"    "pg_catalog.english"
"default_toast_compression" "pglz"
"default_transaction_deferrable"    "off"
"default_transaction_isolation" "read committed"
"default_transaction_read_only" "off"
"dynamic_library_path"  "$libdir"
"dynamic_shared_memory_type"    "posix"
"effective_cache_size"  "3GB"
"effective_io_concurrency"  "200"
"enable_async_append"   "on"
"enable_bitmapscan" "on"
"enable_gathermerge"    "on"
"enable_hashagg"    "on"
"enable_hashjoin"   "on"
"enable_incremental_sort"   "on"
"enable_indexonlyscan"  "on"
"enable_indexscan"  "on"
"enable_material"   "on"
"enable_memoize"    "on"
"enable_mergejoin"  "on"
"enable_nestloop"   "on"
"enable_parallel_append"    "on"
"enable_parallel_hash"  "on"
"enable_partition_pruning"  "on"
"enable_partitionwise_aggregate"    "off"
"enable_partitionwise_join" "off"
"enable_seqscan"    "on"
"enable_sort"   "on"
"enable_tidscan"    "on"
"escape_string_warning" "on"
"event_source"  "PostgreSQL"
"exit_on_error" "off"
"extension_destdir" 
"external_pid_file" "/var/run/postgresql/14-main.pid"
"extra_float_digits"    "1"
"force_parallel_mode"   "off"
"from_collapse_limit"   "8"
"fsync" "on"
"full_page_writes"  "on"
"geqo"  "on"
"geqo_effort"   "5"
"geqo_generations"  "0"
"geqo_pool_size"    "0"
"geqo_seed" "0"
"geqo_selection_bias"   "2"
"geqo_threshold"    "12"
"gin_fuzzy_search_limit"    "0"
"gin_pending_list_limit"    "4MB"
"hash_mem_multiplier"   "1"
"hba_file"  "/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf"
"hot_standby"   "on"
"hot_standby_feedback"  "off"
"huge_page_size"    "0"
"huge_pages"    "try"
"ident_file"    "/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_ident.conf"
"idle_in_transaction_session_timeout"   "0"
"idle_session_timeout"  "0"
"ignore_checksum_failure"   "off"
"ignore_invalid_pages"  "off"
"ignore_system_indexes" "off"
"in_hot_standby"    "off"
"integer_datetimes" "on"
"IntervalStyle" "postgres"
"jit"   "on"
"jit_above_cost"    "100000"
"jit_debugging_support" "off"
"jit_dump_bitcode"  "off"
"jit_expressions"   "on"
"jit_inline_above_cost" "500000"
"jit_optimize_above_cost"   "500000"
"jit_profiling_support" "off"
"jit_provider"  "llvmjit"
"jit_tuple_deforming"   "on"
"join_collapse_limit"   "8"
"krb_caseins_users" "off"
"krb_server_keyfile"    "FILE:/etc/postgresql-common/krb5.keytab"
"lc_collate"    "C.UTF-8"
"lc_ctype"  "C.UTF-8"
"lc_messages"   "C.UTF-8"
"lc_monetary"   "C.UTF-8"
"lc_numeric"    "C.UTF-8"
"lc_time"   "C.UTF-8"
"listen_addresses"  "*"
"lo_compat_privileges"  "off"
"local_preload_libraries"   
"lock_timeout"  "0"
"log_autovacuum_min_duration"   "-1"
"log_checkpoints"   "off"
"log_connections"   "off"
"log_destination"   "stderr"
"log_directory" "log"
"log_disconnections"    "off"
"log_duration"  "off"
"log_error_verbosity"   "default"
"log_executor_stats"    "off"
"log_file_mode" "0600"
"log_filename"  "postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log"
"log_hostname"  "off"
"log_line_prefix"   "%m [%p] %q%u@%d "
"log_lock_waits"    "off"
"log_min_duration_sample"   "-1"
"log_min_duration_statement"    "-1"
"log_min_error_statement"   "error"
"log_min_messages"  "warning"
"log_parameter_max_length"  "-1"
"log_parameter_max_length_on_error" "0"
"log_parser_stats"  "off"
"log_planner_stats" "off"
"log_recovery_conflict_waits"   "off"
"log_replication_commands"  "off"
"log_rotation_age"  "1d"
"log_rotation_size" "10MB"
"log_statement" "none"
"log_statement_sample_rate" "1"
"log_statement_stats"   "off"
"log_temp_files"    "-1"
"log_timezone"  "Europe/Rome"
"log_transaction_sample_rate"   "0"
"log_truncate_on_rotation"  "off"
"logging_collector" "off"
"logical_decoding_work_mem" "64MB"
"maintenance_io_concurrency"    "10"
"maintenance_work_mem"  "512MB"
"max_connections"   "200"
"max_files_per_process" "1000"
"max_function_args" "100"
"max_identifier_length" "63"
"max_index_keys"    "32"
"max_locks_per_transaction" "64"
"max_logical_replication_workers"   "4"
"max_parallel_maintenance_workers"  "2"
"max_parallel_workers"  "4"
"max_parallel_workers_per_gather"   "2"
"max_pred_locks_per_page"   "2"
"max_pred_locks_per_relation"   "-2"
"max_pred_locks_per_transaction"    "64"
"max_prepared_transactions" "0"
"max_replication_slots" "10"
"max_slot_wal_keep_size"    "-1"
"max_stack_depth"   "2MB"
"max_standby_archive_delay" "30s"
"max_standby_streaming_delay"   "30s"
"max_sync_workers_per_subscription" "2"
"max_wal_senders"   "10"
"max_wal_size"  "4GB"
"max_worker_processes"  "4"
"min_dynamic_shared_memory" "0"
"min_parallel_index_scan_size"  "512kB"
"min_parallel_table_scan_size"  "8MB"
"min_wal_size"  "1GB"
"old_snapshot_threshold"    "-1"
"parallel_leader_participation" "on"
"parallel_setup_cost"   "1000"
"parallel_tuple_cost"   "0.1"
"password_encryption"   "scram-sha-256"
"plan_cache_mode"   "auto"
"port"  "5432"
"post_auth_delay"   "0"
"pre_auth_delay"    "0"
"primary_conninfo"  
"primary_slot_name" 
"promote_trigger_file"  
"quote_all_identifiers" "off"
"random_page_cost"  "1.1"
"recovery_end_command"  
"recovery_init_sync_method" "fsync"
"recovery_min_apply_delay"  "0"
"recovery_target"   
"recovery_target_action"    "pause"
"recovery_target_inclusive" "on"
"recovery_target_lsn"   
"recovery_target_name"  
"recovery_target_time"  
"recovery_target_timeline"  "latest"
"recovery_target_xid"   
"remove_temp_files_after_crash" "on"
"restart_after_crash"   "on"
"restore_command"   
"row_security"  "on"
"search_path"   """$user"", public"
"segment_size"  "1GB"
"seq_page_cost" "1"
"server_encoding"   "UTF8"
"server_version"    "14.6 (Ubuntu 14.6-1.pgdg18.04+1)"
"server_version_num"    "140006"
"session_preload_libraries" 
"session_replication_role"  "origin"
"shared_buffers"    "1GB"
"shared_memory_type"    "mmap"
"shared_preload_libraries"  
"ssl"   "on"
"ssl_ca_file"   
"ssl_cert_file" "/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem"
"ssl_ciphers"   "HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL"
"ssl_crl_dir"   
"ssl_crl_file"  
"ssl_dh_params_file"    
"ssl_ecdh_curve"    "prime256v1"
"ssl_key_file"  "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key"
"ssl_library"   "OpenSSL"
"ssl_max_protocol_version"  
"ssl_min_protocol_version"  "TLSv1.2"
"ssl_passphrase_command"    
"ssl_passphrase_command_supports_reload"    "off"
"ssl_prefer_server_ciphers" "on"
"standard_conforming_strings"   "on"
"statement_timeout" "0"
"stats_temp_directory"  "/var/run/postgresql/14-main.pg_stat_tmp"
"superuser_reserved_connections"    "3"
"synchronize_seqscans"  "on"
"synchronous_commit"    "on"
"synchronous_standby_names" 
"syslog_facility"   "local0"
"syslog_ident"  "postgres"
"syslog_sequence_numbers"   "on"
"syslog_split_messages" "on"
"tcp_keepalives_count"  "9"
"tcp_keepalives_idle"   "7200"
"tcp_keepalives_interval"   "75"
"tcp_user_timeout"  "0"
"temp_buffers"  "8MB"
"temp_file_limit"   "-1"
"temp_tablespaces"  
"TimeZone"  "Europe/Rome"
"timezone_abbreviations"    "Default"
"trace_notify"  "off"
"trace_recovery_messages"   "log"
"trace_sort"    "off"
"track_activities"  "on"
"track_activity_query_size" "1kB"
"track_commit_timestamp"    "off"
"track_counts"  "on"
"track_functions"   "none"
"track_io_timing"   "off"
"track_wal_io_timing"   "off"
"transaction_deferrable"    "off"
"transaction_isolation" "read committed"
"transaction_read_only" "off"
"transform_null_equals" "off"
"unix_socket_directories"   "/var/run/postgresql"
"unix_socket_group" 
"unix_socket_permissions"   "0777"
"update_process_title"  "on"
"vacuum_cost_delay" "0"
"vacuum_cost_limit" "200"
"vacuum_cost_page_dirty"    "20"
"vacuum_cost_page_hit"  "1"
"vacuum_cost_page_miss" "2"
"vacuum_defer_cleanup_age"  "0"
"vacuum_failsafe_age"   "1600000000"
"vacuum_freeze_min_age" "50000000"
"vacuum_freeze_table_age"   "150000000"
"vacuum_multixact_failsafe_age" "1600000000"
"vacuum_multixact_freeze_min_age"   "5000000"
"vacuum_multixact_freeze_table_age" "150000000"
"wal_block_size"    "8192"
"wal_buffers"   "16MB"
"wal_compression"   "off"
"wal_consistency_checking"  
"wal_init_zero" "on"
"wal_keep_size" "0"
"wal_level" "replica"
"wal_log_hints" "off"
"wal_receiver_create_temp_slot" "off"
"wal_receiver_status_interval"  "10s"
"wal_receiver_timeout"  "1min"
"wal_recycle"   "on"
"wal_retrieve_retry_interval"   "5s"
"wal_segment_size"  "16MB"
"wal_sender_timeout"    "1min"
"wal_skip_threshold"    "2MB"
"wal_sync_method"   "fdatasync"
"wal_writer_delay"  "200ms"
"wal_writer_flush_after"    "1MB"
"work_mem"  "2621kB"
"xmlbinary" "base64"
"xmloption" "content"
"zero_damaged_pages"    "off"
```

Comment: It may be helpful to share the query you are attempting. The time frame of 1.3s for a request can be normal for a request in some instances. However without knowledge of your DB setup overall, it may be hard for us to advise here.

Comment: What in this output or elsewhere makes you think the table is corrupted?

Comment: Surely nothing you have shown indicates corruption.  If the vacuum output you show have anything to do with the problem?  Does it make it better, make it worse, or just not change it at all?

Comment: I modified the post also putting the explain query, I do not know if you can understand why the query takes 3 minutes to be executed

Comment: Ciao jjanes, Once I launch Autovaccum, the query I launch becomes very fast, it doesn't take all that time to execute